# Mechanizing checkbox with checkbox.check not working

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to mechanize the select devices part of the Apple Dev Portal "Edit iOS Provisioning Profile", which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production) (if you're logged in).

The source looks like this:

```
<form name="profileEdit" method="get" action="https://developer.apple.com/services-developerportal/QH43B2/account/ios/profile/regenProvisioningProfile.action?content-type=text/x-url-arguments&accept=application/json&requestId=838c910b-f63d-843e7b1ce126&userLocale=en_US&teamId=BF5K33D" successURL="/account/ios/profile/profileDownload.action?provisioningProfileId=">
    <input type="hidden" name="distributionType" value='store'/>
    <input type="hidden" name="returnFullObjects" value="false"/>               
    <div class="nameSection">
        <dl>
            <dt class="selectDevices">Devices:</dt>
                <dd class="selectDevices">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="rows">                                              
                            <div><input type="checkbox" name="deviceIds" class="validate" value="8T8RG7HX" id="devices-6" ><span class="title">iPhone 4 - JC</span></div>
                            <div><input type="checkbox" name="deviceIds" class="validate" value="7Y9F8N47" id="devices-7" ><span class="title">iPhone 5 - DP</span></div>
                            <div><input type="checkbox" name="deviceIds" class="validate" value="ZNES97W7" id="devices-8" checked><span class="title">iPhone 5 - JC</span></div>
                            <div><input type="checkbox" name="deviceIds" class="validate" value="CRDSL7S5" id="devices-9" checked><span class="title">iPod 4 inch</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="form-error deviceIds hidden">Please select a Device</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-buttons">
        <a class="button small left cancel"><span>Cancel</span></a>
            <a class="button small blue right submit"><span>Generate</span></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want to do is check all boxes:

```
form = page.form_with(:name => 'profileEdit') or raise UnexpectedContentError
form.checkboxes_with(:name => 'deviceIds').each do |checkbox|
  puts checkbox["id"] # prints correct value of devices-6...
  checkbox.check
end
form.method = 'GET'
form.submit
```

I get no run time errors, however when I refresh the actual page, not all checkboxes are checked as I intended. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried after changing `.each do |checkbox|` to `.each do |c|` or some other var?

Comment: @Bala did not make a difference.

Comment: Are you just parsing the page or visiting the actual page in a browser?

Comment: @Bala visiting the page

Answer (score 0):

As for as I have understood, your issue is that you are visiting the actual page after setting `checkboxes` which will not work.  But if you inspect the results returned after `submit` you will realize that Mechanize has set the check boxes and returned the response.

If you want to visually see that in an actual browser, you may need to use `Watir` / `Webdriver` etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this:

```
form.checkboxes_with(:name => 'deviceIds').each do |checkbox|
  puts checkbox["id"] # prints correct value of devices-6...
  checkbox.check
end
```

What do these result in:

```
tmp1 = form.checkboxes_with(:name => 'deviceIds').map { |cb| cb.check }
tmp2 = form.checkboxes_with(:name => 'deviceIds').map { |cb| cb.checked? }
```

I would expect `[true, true, true, true]` for both.  If not, something is clearing those out.  The `check()` method is implemented in `RadioButton` which does clear the checked state of all buttons of the same name, but it should be limited to `radiobutton` types.  The `checked` attribute is writable by itself, so you could try directly writing it:

```
form.checkboxes_with(:name => 'deviceIds').each do |cb|
  cb.checked = true
end
```

And avoid what may be a bug or inconsistency in that page/mechanize/whatever.  Just a guess, but something to try.

Comment: They do both indeed result in all `true`s. `cb.checked=true` did not work either.